# Does the closed unit ball of $C(E)$ have no extreme points?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $E$ be a bounded closed set in $\mathbb R^n$. Does the closed unit ball of $C(E)$ (the space of continuous functions on $E$ with supremum norm) have no extreme points?

Comment: I don't understand, why would the closure be called a closed unit ball?

Comment: What do you mean by closed unit ball of C?

Comment: I'm sorry, it means the continuous function on the closure of E

Comment: Do you mean the sup-norm?

Comment: yes, use the sub-norm define a closed unit ball on the space of continuous function on the closure of E

Comment: sup or sub? I think it is the supremum norm.

Comment: oh， I'm sorry to spell sub

Comment: I don't know enough about this, but please rewrite your question properly. Write everything down. Also tag it properly. Add functional analysis.

Comment: What about the constant function 1?

Answer (score 0):

For every nonempty compact space $X$, the closed unit ball of the Banach space $C(X)$ has extreme points. Namely, every continuous function  $f: X\to \mathbb K$ such that $|f|\equiv 1$ is an extreme point (here $\mathbb K$ stands for real or complex field).

Assuming the space is [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space), one can show that the above are *all* extreme points of the closed unit ball. Indeed, if $|f(x_0)|<1$, then $|f|<1$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$. By Urysohn's lemma, there is a nonzero continuous function $g$ supported on the set $|f|\le 1-\epsilon$. Then $\|f+t g\|\le 1$ for all $t$ sufficiently close to $0$.

As a special case, the preceding paragraph applies to a closed bounded set in $\mathbb R$,  because it's a metric space.